# Why cannot I use prototype in Object Literals in javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Well I am curios to learn about prototypes in javascript and found many articles however i am not able to understand why am i not able to use prototypes in Object literals in javascript. As we all know, everything is inherited from Object so in that case

```
function Dog() {
}

Dog.prototype = new Animal;
Dog.prototype.bark = function() {
    console.log("Woof! My name is " + this.name);
};
```

If I am able to use prototype in the function why am i not able to use prototype in the object literals for instance the below example

```
 var obj = {
            firstname: 'foo',
            lastname:'bar'
        }
        // this throws an error
        obj.prototype.getMethod = function () {
            console.log('this is a function');
        }
```

I have gone through all this question but it really doesnt answer the reason why cant use prototype in the object literals in javascript. Below are some of the references

[refrence 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388181/how-can-i-attach-prototype-to-object-literals-in-js)

[refrence 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592384/adding-prototype-to-javascript-object-literal)

[refrence 3](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/)

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452414/adding-a-prototype-to-an-object-literal ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the `.prototype` property belongs to function object. You cannot access it from a plain object instance. Basically the constructor-associated `.prototype` property will be used when constructing the internal `[[prototype]]` of an instance. Here you are having an instance, if you want to add the function to the prototype chain of it, then you have to modify it by

```
var obj = { firstname: 'foo', lastname:'bar' };
var pro = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
pro.getMethod = function () {
  console.log('this is a function');
};
```

As @bergi pointed out, there is a risk of adding the `getMethod` to all the instances if we follow the above approach. But in order to avoid that you could alternatively do,

```
var obj = { firstname: 'foo', lastname:'bar' };
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, Object.create({getMethod : function(){
  console.log("Hello");
}}));

console.log(obj.getMethod()); //"Hello"
```

Comment: every object has been inherited, right? then why are we not able to acces the prototype property in the object literals, how is the object literal so different from the function in javascript?

Comment: Notice that `pro === Object.prototype`, so you'll probably do *not* want to modify it

Comment: @LijinJohn Because instances are very different from constructors. To clear your confusion, you'll might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript

Comment: @Bergi Yup. getMethod will be available in all the object instances not only this one.

Comment: @Bergi wouldn't the newly updated approach resolves the problem that we were talking about?

Comment: The `Object.create` is unnecessary (you'd want something like `Object.create(Object.prototype, {getMethod:…/*descriptor*/})` if you used that), but yes `Object.setPrototypeOf` solves the problem of creating global properties on all objects

Answer (score 0):

With ES2015 and later, you can use the literal `__proto__` as the property name to setup the prototype right in the object literal:

```
const myProto = {
  propertyExists: function(name) {
    return name in this;
  },
};
const myNumbers = {
  __proto__: myProto,
  array: [1, 6, 7],
};
myNumbers.propertyExists('array'); // => true
myNumbers.propertyExists('collection'); // => false
```

[Here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/why-object-literals-in-javascript-are-cool/) is where I got the example from.

[Here](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-__proto__-property-names-in-object-initializers) are details of this in the spec.